# Expectation of the realized volatility

Tags: volatility, finance-mathematics, self-study, stochastic

I was reading [Zhang and Wang 2023](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/373170469_Generalized_Method_of_Moments_Estimation_of_Realized_Stochastic_Volatility_Model) and I have some doubts regarding it.  The realized Stochastic Volatility Model is expressed as follows:

$$\begin{matrix}
y_t = \exp \big( \frac{h_t}{2} \big) \epsilon_t \quad \quad \quad
& & & \epsilon_t\sim \text{N}(0,1), \\[12pt]
z_t = \varsigma+h_t+u_t \quad \quad \ \ \
& & & \ \ u_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2_u), \\[12pt]
h_{t+1} = \mu+\phi(h_t-\mu)+\eta_t \
& & & \ \ \ \eta_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2_\eta), \\[12pt]
h_1 = \mu+\epsilon_0 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
& & & \ \ \ \ \ \ \epsilon_0 \sim N(0,\frac{\sigma^2_\eta}{1-\phi^2}). \\[12pt]
\end{matrix}$$

To ensure the strict stationarity and iterative nature of the stochastic process, the persistence parameter $|\phi| < 1$ is assumed in the
logarithmic volatility equation $h_t$ and set $h_1$

**My question:** Why do we have the expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}(z_t) = \varsigma+ \frac{\mu}{1-\phi}?$$

I cannot see why the expectation of $h_t$ should be $\frac{\mu}{1-\phi}$. $h_t$ should follow an AR(1) process and the expected value of an AR(1) process with drift is $\frac{\mu}{1-\phi}$ but in this case we have an additional term given by $-\phi \mu$.  Am I missing something?  Can someone explain why the $\mathbb{E}(z_t)$ is given by the above result?

my attempt was: since the AR(1) process is stationary given that $|\phi|<1$ the mean is constant over time and  [\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(h) - \phi\mathbb{E}(h) &= \mu - \phi\mu \\
(1-\phi)\mathbb{E}(h) &= \mu(1-\phi).
\end{align*}]
which gives $\mathbb{E}(h) = \mu$
why they got $\frac{\mu}{1-\phi}$?

Comment: Cross-posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626943).